# Troubles with gtk

Tags: gtk, inkscape

I am having issues with Inkscape not rendering text correctly, and illustrations are not showing unless I slightly adjust the borders on my Windows machine. To troubleshoot, I started Inkscape from the terminal to catch error messages and received the following error:

> Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkiconhelper.c:494:ensure_surface_for_gicon: assertion failed (error == NULL): Failed to load /snap/inkscape/10536/data-dir/icons/Adwaita/16x16/status/image-missing.png: Unrecognized image file format (gdk-pixbuf-error-quark, 3)

I am running Fedora 38 on an AMD Ryzen 5 machine with 16GB of RAM.

Comment: The issue is solved when I changed from X11 to Wayland graphic platform.

Comment: May be you should report the bug to the Inkscape team.